# Show/hide paragraph based on div height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have following code and I am trying to hide the 2nd Paragraph by default and show it when blue circle is clicked and div is expanded that paragraph should display

Here is the code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Store inner height in a data property:
  $(".added-msg-inner").removeClass("added-msg-inner").each(function() {
    $(this).data({
      innerHeight: $(this).height()
    });
  }).addClass('added-msg-inner');
  $(".added-msg-inner > p:nth-child(2)").hide();
  $(".downarrow").click(function() {
    // Get specific divView and innerHeight related to this down arrow
    var $divView = $(this).siblings(".added-msg-inner");
    var innerHeight = $divView.data("innerHeight");

    $divView.animate({
      height: $divView.height() == 95 ? innerHeight : "95px"
    }, 500);
    $('i', this).attr("class",
      $divView.height() == 95 ? "fa fa-angle-up" :
      "fa fa-angle-down");
    return false;

    var $minHeight = 95;
    if ($(this).height() > $minHeight) {
      $(".added-msg-inner > p:nth-child(2)").show();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.added-msg2 {
  padding: 3% 1%;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #333333;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

.added-msg-inner {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 95px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.downarrow {
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: -12px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #003478;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="added-msg2">
  <div class="added-msg-inner">
    <p>Message added by agent user on<br> Sat, Jun 24th, 2017 (5:03AM)</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries</p>
    <p><i class="fa fa-paperclip" aria-hidden="true"></i> ABCFileName.pdf</p>
  </div>
  <div class="downarrow"><i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've amended your code so that the 2nd paragraph (message) is hidden on load, and on blue circle click, the paragraph slides open.

I wasn't sure as to the purpose of some of the styling on the paragraph so I've removed it. The height of the parent div will expand automatically so the overflow hidden etc. probably isn't needed.

A lot of the JS looked like it might be unnecessary, the snippet I've added below is enough to expand the paragraph as you described. Also, I've added some more semantic classes to the HTML (paragraphs).

Here's the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.downarrow').on("click", function() {
    $('.added-msg-content').slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.added-msg2 {
  padding: 3% 1%;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #333333;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

.added-msg-inner {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.downarrow {
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: -12px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #003478;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.added-msg-content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="added-msg2">
  <div class="added-msg-inner">
    <p class="added-msg-author">Message added by agent user on<br> Sat, Jun 24th, 2017 (5:03AM)</p>
    <p class="added-msg-content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries</p>
    <p><i class="fa fa-paperclip" aria-hidden="true"></i> ABCFileName.pdf</p>
  </div>
  <div class="downarrow"><i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, you made it very easy! +1 for compact solution

Comment: Glad it was helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `return` statement and use the callback function of jQuerys [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) methode to show the paragraph after animation is finished:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Store inner height in a data property:
  $(".added-msg-inner").removeClass("added-msg-inner").each(function() {
    $(this).data({
      innerHeight: $(this).height()
    });
  }).addClass('added-msg-inner');
  $(".added-msg-inner > p:nth-child(2)").hide();
  $(".downarrow").click(function() {
    // Get specific divView and innerHeight related to this down arrow
    var $divView = $(this).siblings(".added-msg-inner");
    var innerHeight = $divView.data("innerHeight");

    $divView.animate({
      height: $divView.height() == 95 ? innerHeight : "95px"
    }, 500, function() {
      // Animation complete:
      if ($divView.height() > 95) {
        $(".added-msg-inner > p:nth-child(2)").show();
      } else {
        $(".added-msg-inner > p:nth-child(2)").hide();
      }
    });
    $('i', this).attr("class", $divView.height() == 95 ? "fa fa-angle-up" : "fa fa-angle-down");
  });
});
```

```css
.added-msg2 {
  padding: 3% 1%;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #333333;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
}

.added-msg-inner {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 95px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.downarrow {
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: -12px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #003478;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="added-msg2">
  <div class="added-msg-inner">
    <p>Message added by agent user on<br> Sat, Jun 24th, 2017 (5:03AM)</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries</p>
    <p><i class="fa fa-paperclip" aria-hidden="true"></i> ABCFileName.pdf</p>
  </div>
  <div class="downarrow"><i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
</div>
```